# iOS share extension: need to share all the pdf files including web link pdf files through my share extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I need to share pdf files from other application through my Share extension. In my share extension, I am using this `NSExtensionActivationRule`

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
<string>SUBQUERY (
        extensionItems,
        $extensionItem,
        SUBQUERY (
           $extensionItem.attachments,
           $attachment,(
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf";
           || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url";
        ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
   ).@count == 1
</string>
```

For URL contents, I was able to see my app icon in all the activation controllers of other applications. But I need to activate the extension only for PDF urls.

Can I create an `NSExtensionActivationRule`, which can select all the pdf files for sharing through Share extension including URL and contents.?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to to get my share extension to recognize PDFs, images, GIFs, and plain text by using the following subquery in my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
<string>SUBQUERY (
      extensionItems, 
      $extensionItem,
      SUBQUERY (
          $extensionItem.attachments, 
          $attachment,
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" ||
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text" ||
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" ||
           ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.compuserve.gif"
        ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
        ).@count == 1
</string>
```

Comment: "I need to activate the extension only for PDF urls" was the question